# Volume is not coming when setting the Phone to ringer programmatically

Tags: android, volume

I want to change the phone mode to ringer when a call comes. It changes to ringing mode but the music/sound is not played.

Do I need to set any permission for it. I've set the following permission for it:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

I used following code to set it to ringer mode:

```
am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,am.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING),AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
```

I tested it in Samsung Galaxy Y